# Hyperledger Composer BusinessNetwork Connection - 0.14.3 cannot connect

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to use BusinessNetworkConnection for NodeJS, but how do I get the credentials from a deployed BNA on playground and save it in my server directory?

I am getting

```
2017-11-03T13:07:32.83-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR (node:62) 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): Error: Error trying login and get user Context. 
Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. 
Error: Enrollment failed with errors 
[[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
```

when I try using the code

```
const BusinessNetworkConnection = require("composer-client").BusinessNetworkConnection;
this.businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
this.CONNECTION_PROFILE_NAME = "ibm-bc-org1";
this.businessNetworkIdentifier = "giveback";
this.businessNetworkConnection
  .connect(
    this.CONNECTION_PROFILE_NAME,
    this.businessNetworkIdentifier,
    "admin",
    "adminpw"
  )
  .then(result => {
    this.businessNetworkDefinition = result;
    console.log("BusinessNetworkConnection: ", result);
  })
```

I have a directory `/home/vcap/app/.composer-connection-profiles/ibm-bc-org1` with a `connection.json` file that references `/home/vcap/app/.composer-credentials/ibm-bc-org1` for my  credentials. The code worked for `composer@0.13.2` but now I moved over to `composer@0.14.3`. I removed the previous credentials and created a new playground etc, everything is fresh and clean.

Comment: adminpwd is not the secret for the CA bootstrap user unless you have actually setup the CA server with that secret. The normal one is adminpw

Comment: I changed this to `adminpw` but it is still throwing the same error :(

Comment: If the secret is now correct, then your credentials directory must still have an admin identity in there that is not one the CA Server is expecting. This happens if you restart the CA server or another process has re-enrolled admin and thus made the original one invalid for that CA Server

Comment: Is there a way for me to save the `admin` credential that is already there? Currently, I am just pushing my server with nothing inside `.composer-credentials/ibm-bc-org1`

Comment: `2017-11-03T17:13:59.38-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR (node:53) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered: admin)` I am getting this error right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a work around when something like this happens. Because I am trying to connect with the credentials that Composer created the with `admin || adminpw`. You can just define a new participant in your model file and then give that participant system permissions to query and listen for events that the `Historian` emits.

For example in your `model.cto`:

```
participant ServerAdmin identified by serverhash {
  // ServerAdmin is a type of participant 
  o String serverhash
}
```

And in your `permissions.acl` add :

```
rule ServerAdminUser {
  description: "Grant business network administrators full access to 
  user resources"
  participant: "org.acme.sample.ServerAdmin"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "**"
  action: ALLOW
}

rule ServerAdminSystem {
  description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
  participant: "org.acme.sample.ServerAdmin"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}
```

Then after the network has been deployed by Composer on playground, you can add this participant VIA the REST API, and issue it a new identity. This will give you a `User ID` and `User Secret` with which you can use in `BusinessNetworkConnection.connect()`